# Expose service on local kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running a local kubernetes bundled with docker on Mac OS.

How can I expose a service, so that I can access the service via a browser on my Mac?

I've created:

a) deployment including apache httpd.

b) service via yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apaches
spec:
  selector:
    app: web
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
  externalIPs:
  - 192.168.1.10 # Network IP of my Mac
```

My service looks like:

```
$ kubectl get service apaches
NAME      TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE
apaches   NodePort   10.102.106.158   192.168.1.10   80:31137/TCP   14m
```

I can locally access the service in my kubernetes cluster by `wget $CLUSTER-IP`

I tried to call http://192.168.1.10/ on my Mac, but it doesn't work.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618683/kubernetes-minikube-cannot-expose-service-on-public-ip-range) deals to a similar issue. But the solution does not help, because I do not know which IP I can use.

**Update**

Thanks to Michael Hausenblas I worked out a solution using [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress).
Nevertheless there are still some open questions:

- What is the meaning of a service's externalIP? Why do I need an externalIP when I do not directly access a service from external?
- What is the meaning of the service port 31137?
- - The kubernetes docs describe a method to [publish a service in minikube via NodePort][4]. Is this also possible with kubernetes bundled on docker?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several solutions to expose services in kubernetes:
http://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/

Here are my solutions according to alesnosek for a local kubernetes bundled with docker:

**1. hostNetwork**

```
hostNetwork: true
```

Dirty (the host network should not be shared for security reasons) => I did not check this solution.

**2. hostPort**

```
hostPort: 8086
```

Does not apply to services => I did not check this solution.

**3. NodePort**

Expose the service by defining a nodePort:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apaches
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30000
  selector:
    app: apache
```

**4. LoadBalancer**

**EDIT**
@MathObsessed posted the [solution in his anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60111530/1909531).

**5. Ingress**

**a. Install [Ingress Controller](https://github.com/jnewland/local-dev-with-docker-for-mac-kubernetes)**

```
git clone https://github.com/jnewland/local-dev-with-docker-for-mac-kubernetes.git

kubectl apply -f nginx-ingress/namespaces/nginx-ingress.yaml -Rf nginx-ingress
```

**b. Configure Ingress**

`kubectl apply -f apache-ing.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: apache-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: apaches
          servicePort: 80
```

Now I can access my apache deployed with kubernetes by calling http://localhost/

**Remarks for using [local-dev-with-docker-for-mac-kubernetes](https://github.com/jnewland/local-dev-with-docker-for-mac-kubernetes)**

- The repo simplifies the [deployment of the offical ingress-nginx controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/README.md)
- For production use I would follow the [official guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/README.md).
- The repos ships with a [tiny full featured ingress example](https://github.com/jnewland/local-dev-with-docker-for-mac-kubernetes/tree/master/httpbin). Very useful for getting quickly a working example application.

**Further documentation**

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress

Comment: For the "Ingress" type, it's worth mentioning that there are a lot of different options. [Istio](https://github.com/istio/istio), [Traefik](https://github.com/traefik/traefik), etc.

Answer (score 17):

For those still looking for an answer. I've managed to achieve this by adding another Kube service just to expose my app to localhost calls (via browser or Postman):

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apaches-published
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: web
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Try it now on: http://localhost:8080

Comment: I don't get an external ip for type: Loadbalancer:

apaches   LoadBalancer   10.98.28.154   <pending>    ...

Comment: Maybe that is because your 8080 port is already taken? For example you've got another local service or a program that uses this port? I would try two things at first:
1) `docker ps -a` (to see running processes)
2) try a fancy port like `8743` or `8090` instead of `8080` just to make sure no other application is using it
3) I am using Docker Desktop, maybe you're on Linux and things work a bit differently there
4) Also I am using `kubectl` and you may be using `minikube`?

Comment: You're right, after fixing the incorrect port I can access the service.

Answer (score 7):

Really simple example

### METHOD1

```sh
$ kubectl create deployment nginx-dep --image=nginx --replicas=2
```

- Get the pods

```sh
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-dep-5c5477cb4-76t9q   1/1     Running   0          7h5m
nginx-dep-5c5477cb4-9g84j   1/1     Running   0          7h5m
```

- Access the pod using `kubectl port`

```sh
$ kubectl port-forward nginx-dep-5c5477cb4-9g84j 8888:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8888 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:8888 -> 80
```

- Now do a `curl` to the `localhost:8888`

```sh
$ curl -v http://localhost:8888
```

#### METHOD2

You can expose `port 80` of the deployment (where the application is runnin i.e. nginx port)
via a NodePort

```sh
$ kubectl expose deployment nginx-dep --name=nginx-dep-svc --type=NodePort --port=80
```

- Get the service

```sh
$ kubectl get svc 
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP        31d
nginx-dep-svc   NodePort    10.110.80.21   <none>        80:31239/TCP   21m
```

- Access the deployment using hte NodePort

```sh
$ curl http://localhost:31239
```

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in Matthias Ms answer there are several ways.

As the offical Kubernetes documentation specifically describes [using a `Service` with a `type` `NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) I wanted to describe the workflow.

> `NodePort`: Exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the `NodePort`). A `ClusterIP` Service, to which the `NodePort` Service routes, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the `NodePort` Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`.
>
> If you set the `type` field to `NodePort`, the Kubernetes control plane allocates a port from a range specified by `--service-node-port-range` flag (default: 30000-32767). Each node proxies that port (the same port number on every Node) into your Service. Your Service reports the allocated port in its `.spec.ports[*].nodePort` field.

Setup a Service with a `type` of `NodePort`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
  clusterIP: 10.0.171.239
  type: NodePort
```

Then you can check on which port the Service is exposed to via

```
kubectl get svc

NAME                           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
my-service                     NodePort       10.103.218.215   <none>        9376:31040/TCP               52s
```

and access it via localhost using the exposed port. E.g.

```
curl http://localhost:31040
```

Comment: have you checked that if it is exposed on 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: ```Failed to connect to localhost port 32179: Connection refused```