# k8s (k3s): expose a service automatically

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

Is there a way to kubernetes creates an ingress according to a just deployed service?

I've just created a k3d cluster and I''ve deployed my springboot service.

I've deployed a manifest with a `DeploymentConfig` and a `Service`.

I'd like this just created service is available out of kubernetes...

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to define that in your deployment(s). There are numerous options - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221085/1318694

Comment: Was any of the options provided useful to you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expose service on local kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219171/expose-service-on-local-kubernetes)