# Test Pod's external IP on a Kubernetes one node cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, webapi

I am working with the docker desktop version and have got a one node Kubernetes cluster.
I have a containerized web api that is represented by the pod.

I want to give the Pod an IP adress other than the localhost.

I created a service to expose my pod and used an external IP, here is the **yaml** file :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pred-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: predictim
  ports:
  - port: 1080
    targetPort: 1080
    nodePort: 30001
  externalIPs:
    - 80.11.12.10
```

When I launch a service describe I get as external IPs : localhost, 80.11.12.10

When I test the pod with PowerShell :

- using `Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri http://localhost:1080/predict` --> it works fine
- using `Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri http://80.11.12.10:1080/predict` --> bad address error

I don't know how to do test the assigned External-IP.

I'm certainly missing something, can you please help me to understand.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: The `externalIPs:` setting doesn't really do anything.  If you have some other controller that creates load balancers (maybe you're in a cloud environment) then it's a place for that controller to record what it did, but putting a value there doesn't cause the cluster to do anything.

Comment: [Expose service on local kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219171/expose-service-on-local-kubernetes) walks through some options for making a service visible; does one of these work for you?

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice and the link. I will try the Ingess method. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve is to use `hostPort`. This will basically mimic the `-p 1080:1080` option on docker run command. You should be able to use your public  IP too since it's only one node. This has to be done in pod template.

```
ports:
- containerPort: 1080
  hostPort: 1080
```

A more elegant way is using [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/usage/). With MetalLB installed you can just make your service type LoadBalancer even if you are not on cloud.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice and the link. Thanks again. I'll give a feedback if I'll use MetalLB.